# Why is OpenGL version 0.0?

Tags: c++, opengl

I was troubleshooting an OpenGL application on a new computer when I discovered that GLFW could not create a window with the specified version of OpenGL. I created a minimal version of the application to test the version of OpenGL created, and no matter what version I hint, the version I get is 0.0. Do I simply not have OpenGL? This seems impossible, since glxgears runs and glxinfo suggests that I have version 2.1.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>

int main(int argc, const char *argv[]) {
    if(!glfwInit()) {
        return 1;
    }
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 2);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 1);
    auto win = glfwCreateWindow(640, 480, "", NULL, NULL);
    if(!win) {
        return 1;
    }
    int major = 0, minor = 0;
    glfwMakeContextCurrent(win);
    glGetIntegerv(GL_MAJOR_VERSION, &major);
    glGetIntegerv(GL_MINOR_VERSION, &minor);
    std::cout << "Initialized with OpenGL "
        << major << "." << minor << std::endl;
    glfwDestroyWindow(win);
    glfwTerminate();
}
```

The output of the application is "Initialized with OpenGL 0.0". A window briefly opens and closes and the application terminates without errors.

Comment: AFAIK reported values are ultimately up to your driver. What OS and driver version are you using?

Comment: I'm using Linux 4.4.0-36, Ubuntu, and I'm not sure about the driver. However my vendor is Intel Open Source Technology Center and my renderer is Mesa DRI, Ironlake Mobile.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `GL_MAJOR_VERSION` and `GL_MINOR_VERSION` queries were introduced in GL 3.0. Prior to that, this will just generate an `GL_INVALID_ENUM` error during the `glGetIntegerv` call, and leave your variables untouched.

You have to use `glGetString(GL_VERSION)` to reliably get the verison number if you can't make sure that you are on a >= 3.0 context. If you need those as numbers, you'll have to manually parse the string.